# Message body was 'null', which is not a value of a supported type

Tags: publish-subscribe, anypoint-studio, subscribe, mule4

Message body was 'null', which is not a value of a supported type ERROR
I need to publish my payload which is:

```json
{
    
     "items": {
       "compressString": "Unquitternuncaganayunganadornuncaabandona",
       "index": [2,10,16,21,23,26,34,40]
     }
}
```

But I am getting an error message: Message body was 'null', which is not a value of a supported type. What will be the supported type to resolve the issue?][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X00c7.png)

Comment: That's a value in the debugger. You should show the error in the logs instead. You should not use images but text for the errors and logs. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. You should add details of the flow, as text XML. Note, this is related to ActiveMQ, not Anypoint MQ which is a completely different product. Please also add to the question the exact version of Mule, the JMS connector and the ActiveMQ libraries.

Comment: How is this related to ActiveMQ?

Comment: He is using Mule Runtime with the JMS Connector to connect to an ActiveMQ queue. Title was incorrectly pointing to a different technology. The error is coming from a JMSException.

Comment: How do you know he's connecting to ActiveMQ? I don't see any mention of ActiveMQ in the original question. Also, how do you know he's using Mule Runtime with the JMS Connector? I don't see any mention of that either. FWIW, a `JMSException` could come from *any* JMS implementation, and I see no mention of that either.

Comment: I deduced it from the screenshot, which shows a Mule 4 application being debugged and a JMSException. I assumed the JMS implementation was ActiveMQ because the originally mentioned Anypoint MQ is not compatible with JMS. But this all should be confirmed by the poster. I previously asked for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can add this to the list of why screenshots are generally a bad idea. I didn't even see it. Anyway, the `JmsIllegalBodyException` is not coming from ActiveMQ as that class doesn't exist in the ActiveMQ code-base and that's not a standard JMS exception. That error message also doesn't appear in the ActiveMQ code-base. Despite the fact the screenshot mentions "ActiveMQ" I see no evidence that it is actually involved here so I'm removing the tag until further details are presented.

Answer (score 0):

Without having all the information I can only make an educated guess that the application is using an old version of the JMS connector which is triggering a know issue already fixed years ago related to publish operations with data in streams. Try updating to the latest release.